# Request.Browser.Browser and ask.com toolbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

We're having a strange issue with our site and the ask.com toolbar. Somehow, if we install the ask.com toolbar on a client in our network, it's overriding the Request.Browser.Browser and Request.Browser.MajorVersion on other clients that do NOT have the ask.com toolbar installed. However, the user agent string is correct on those other clients that do have the toolbar installed. The problem is we are restricting access to our site based on the Request.Browser.Browser and Request.Browser.MajorVersion and if the ask.com toolbar is installed somewhere it's screwing up the logic we're using to restrict access.

UPDATE: Apparently, after a short period of time, the problem goes away and the Request.Browser.Browser and Request.Browser.MajorVersion are reported correctly even though no changes are made.

So I guess I really have two questions:
1) How can installing a third-party toolbar on one client have an effect on the ASP.Net Request object?
2) Where does the ASP.Net Request object get its info (because it doesn't appear to be parsing the user agent string to get it)?

Comment: I sure hope you're not using that to block nonIE browsers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Third party toolbar's like specifically ASK over writes the user agent string of the browser.
2. User agent info is passed to the server every time a request is made. ASP.NET Request.ServerVariables["UserAgent"] will have this value information and ASP.NET uses this information against browser caps to identify the browser.